# What happens in MySQL if you try to insert a value into a VARCHAR that can't fit?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a function like

```
function log_visitor_info ( $ip, $pgurl, $refurl, $aginfo )
{
    global $wpdb, $ipsToIgnore; 
    if (!in_array($ip, $ipsToIgnore)) $wpdb->insert('wp_nas_visits',  array('ip'=>$ip,'refurl'=>$refurl,'pgurl'=>$pgurl,'aginfo'=>$aginfo));
}
```

which inserts rows into my MySQL database and wondering what happens if there is a value to large to enter into a column. For example, the column `aginfo` is of type `VARCAHR (250)`, so what happens if the string `$aginfo` has length 251? Will my site crash? Do I need to protect against this by doing something like

```
if ( strlen($aginfo) > 250 ) $aginfo = substr($aginfo, 0, 250);
```

to protect against this?

Comment: It will save it and cut it, at least that is my experience, eg 500 words saved into a 200 long varchar, a total of 300 words would be missing.

Comment: from my experience the string gets truncated and you may get a warning depending on how your site works. but generally when developing tables for a database you should be anticipating the field size and if you have user input which gets saved to a database you always set the `maxlength` attribute.....because users are idiots

Comment: @Memor-X What is the `maxlength` attribute?

Comment: @PeterThiel [input maxlength attribute on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp)

Comment: Yes it's always important to do double check when validating user input, and of course don't forget to sanitize everything before saving it into your database.

Comment: @Memor-X Can't someone get around that with Javascript?

Comment: @PeterThiel yes if they are using a browser's console or a userscript but then if their data is getting truncated because they are altering the page via their own javascript then stuff them. after all you can only account for any javascript *you've* added to the page, not what the mirid of userscripts do

Comment: *Personally,* I would first check if it is less or equal to `if ( strlen($aginfo) <= 250 ){ // execute } else { // kill it or do something else }`. On many occasions and this is most important when dealing with hashed passwords, that it ***will fail silently*** if a hash was saved with a column not being within the required length, and doing a query on select, where password checking always fails because of it; least, 9 times out of 10 times by my experiences here with those related questions on Stack.

Comment: *"Can't someone get around that with Javascript?"* If I may answer; don't rely on a JS solution, use a serverside method. JS can always be disabled by a user. If you're going to want to use a JS method, use both; JS and serverside and cover all your bases ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the official MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html) (emphasis mine):

> If **strict** SQL mode is not enabled and you assign a value to a `CHAR` or
> `VARCHAR` column that exceeds the column's maximum length, the value is
> **truncated** to fit and a *warning* is generated. For truncation of
> nonspace characters, you can cause an *error* to occur (rather than a
> *warning*) and suppress insertion of the value by using strict SQL mode.
> See [Section 5.1.11, “Server SQL Modes”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html).